# Sprite Kit Swift Jumping Character

Tags: xcode, swift

Right now, I am trying to use impulses/forces to make my character jump.  I was using gravity so it looks like they are jumping, but the sizes of the jumps were different overtime.  Here is my code for attempting to make the character jump, but when I do it, it does not work.

Here is the jumping code I have right now:

```
func Bigpersonjump () {
    BigPerson.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0)
    BigPerson.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0.0, 10.0))


    println("Detected")

}

Here is the code for spawning the character:

self.BigPerson = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "1")
         //self.BigPerson = SKSpriteNode(texture: BigPersonTexture)
        self.BigPerson.size.height = self.size.height / 8
        self.BigPerson.size.width = self.size.width / 13
        self.BigPerson.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) / 2 ,             self.frame.size.height / 2.2)


        self.BigPerson.zPosition = 9
        BigPerson.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: BigPerson.size)
        BigPerson.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        BigPerson.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        BigPerson.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.BigPersonCategory.rawValue
        BigPerson.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        BigPerson.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.ScoreCategory.rawValue
        BigPerson.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.ScoreCategory.rawValue


        var distanceToMove = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + 2.0 * BigPerson.size.width)
        var moveBigPerson = SKAction.moveByX(distanceToMove * 5.3, y: 0.0, duration: NSTimeInterval (0.02 * distanceToMove))
        BigPerson.runAction(moveBigPerson)
        BigPerson.runAction(LeftSideRunning)
        self.addChild(self.BigPerson)
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: Why do you set physicsBody.dynamic to false if you use applyImpulse ?

Comment: I reset the dynamic to true, and when its supposed to jump, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

For realistic jump you need to use only applyImpulse, not SKActions (e.g. on user's tap).
Physics body should be dynamic (in your code it is false).
Check different values for impulse value, because you body may be too heavy.
Also please check friction value for both body and surface (as I see in your code you are trying to move it horizontally).
Also try different directions, may be you are trying to jump in the wrong direction.